# android Restful GET operation

Tags: android, rest

I need to get an image using webservice which is rest.And most of the tutorials are about click the button in order to trigger the process.I need to implement this such a way that when activity opens images has to be loaded immediately without trigger or clicking the button or something.I just need a source or idea.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement an Asynctask and call it onCreate.

Here is an example on how to do it;

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
.
.
.
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    .
    .
    .

    // Calling async task to get json
    new GetContacts().execute();
}

/**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
 * */
private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                    String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                    String gender = c.getString(TAG_GENDER);

                    // Phone node is JSON Object
                    JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject(TAG_PHONE);
                    String mobile = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE);
                    String home = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_HOME);
                    String office = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_OFFICE);

                    // tmp hashmap for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    contact.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    contact.put(TAG_EMAIL, email);
                    contact.put(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, mobile);

                    // adding contact to contact list
                    contactList.add(contact);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                MainActivity.this, contactList,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_EMAIL,
                        TAG_PHONE_MOBILE }, new int[] { R.id.name,
                        R.id.email, R.id.mobile });

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

}

As you can see, you only need to call the asynctask (new GetContacts().execute();) onCreate and it will behave as you design it.

References: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

Write your code in onCreate() or onResume() method of activity.

For downloading images you can use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) and [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).

For communication between app and webservice you can use [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/).

Also for more information you can read this tutorial  [Retrofit - Getting Started and Create an Android Client](https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client)

Answer (score 0):

Write your code for loading image in `onCreate()` method of `Activity`. So user don't need to trigger or clicking the button or something.

Comment: onCreate() will be called every time the activity is recreated including orientation changes. Check out the android lifecycle page http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html. Maybe include some caching type mechanism  so you dont have to download the image every time.Could be overkill if youre just learning a tutorial but it's a good thing to understand.

Comment: You can use Image Downloder that will cache image for you. Please check https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader